# Inline vs constexpr for a static const getter?

Tags: c++, c++11, inline, constexpr

In the following piece of code, what function will allow the best optimization for an external use and why ? Is the "Version 4" allowed in C++ 2011 ?

```
template<unsigned int TDIM> class MyClass 
{
    public:
        static inline unsigned int size()           {return _size;} // Version 1
        static inline const unsigned int size()     {return _size;} // Version 2
        static constexpr unsigned int size()        {return _size;} // Version 3
        static inline constexpr unsigned int size() {return _size;} // Version 4
    protected:
        static const unsigned int _size = TDIM*3;
};
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: All of these getters sound worthless. I'd just expose the constant static field.

Comment: But admitting that I need a getter for my "real" program (not this example) what would be the best ?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know your "real" program.

Comment: Just go with version 5: `static const unsigned int size() {return _size;}`. Unless you really need a compile time value, there's no need to use `constexpr`. And those functions are already inline, so there's no need to use `inline` either.

Comment: I'm guessing that any good compiler will optimize these all down to the same thing. If you're using `g++`, try compiling all four with `-S` and look at the generated assembly.

Comment: @mfontanini `const` on the return value is worthless (GCC will even warn on some levels).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes yeah it's useless actually. My comment didn't originally have that const, IDK why I added it...

Comment: @Vincent: Unless you provide a good reason not to do it, follow R. Martinho's suggestion: make the field public. Adding an extra layer of indirection and worrying whether it will be optimized away seems a pointless exercise.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: It's not completely pointless. It might be called on an instance through CRTP, in which case it might be necessary to make it a function.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I am not sure I follow. In what context can a `static` member function be called that access to a `static` variable would not be viable?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Take a look at `std::allocator`. The functions are (likely) `static`, but that's irrelevant to the users of that class (e.g. `std::vector`). A similar situation happens in CRTP, although I don't have a great example right now. The bottom line is that when you're writing generic code, you don't want to assume things you don't need to hold true.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The standard requires an interface for `std::allocator` and that interface has no `static` member functions, so that is not a valid example. I still don't think there is a single case where one can be used and not the other.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: *"The standard requires an interface"*... Sure, but you completely missed what I was trying to say... *"I still don't think there is a **single** case"* I can't believe you make generalizations so easily, as if you've already seen all the code humanity is going to write in the future! And yet it's really so much more common than you think, I'm not sure what else to tell you... but here: http://ideone.com/ln0SY

Comment: @Mehrdad: That is not even a proper use of CRTP, you would not cast `this`, just call `T::function` :) But you missed my point, if you are designing the class, you get to choose how to access, so the CRT could just as well use `T::N`, that is what I was trying to say: in all contexts where you can access a `static` function you can access a `static` attribute. That is the reason for the *unless you provide a good reason not to...* in the original comment :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Have you ever used ATL/WTL? They do exactly what I do here, and I'm pretty darn sure it's "proper use of CRTP". I have no idea what you mean with your correction, but saying `T::function` doesn't even *work* if the function is an instance member! (For starters, take a look here: http://code.google.com/p/ie-toolbar/source/browse/trunk/gridctrl_atl_src/atlcontrols.h?r=113#4984)

Comment: @Mehrdad: I have not used ATL/WTL, the call to a static function through an instance is correct, but if you want to call a static function you need not perform a cast on `this`, or use inheritance at all, you can call static member functions through the type directly.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: What?? How is `CDialog` supposed to know whether `GetLayout` is `static` inside `CMyDialog`? (And even if it did, *why should it even care*?) And what if `CMyDialog` is going to be written 5 years *after* when `CDialog` is written and published, by a completely different author?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Are you saying that `GetLayout` is `static`? Or that `CDialog` does not *know* the functions in it's own library? -- Look, seriously, there is no point in discussing this, if it makes you happier, there are cases where you need a function to fulfill some interface --I am yet to see a case where a `static` function would be part of an interface, but it could be possible--, and for those cases, you just need to do what the interface requires you to do.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Ah, there's your crucial mistake! `CDialog` and `CMyDialog` **are most certainly NOT in the same library** (or written by the same author, or at the same time, etc.) The **entire point** of CRTP is to provide *compile-time **polymorphism*** to **consumers** of your class: `CDialog` is in the *framework*, and `CMyDialog` is written by its **user**. Seriously, if you aren't used to CRTP, just go play with ATL/WTL for a bit, and you'll see what I'm talking about. But until you understand the concepts of CRTP and polymorphism, you won't understand what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe that the code in `<random>` sets a good example, but also need not be followed slavishly.  In `<random>` you see both of these styles:

```
template<unsigned int TDIM> class MyClass 
{
    public:
        static constexpr unsigned int size() {return _size;}  // 1
        static constexpr unsigned int dim = TDIM;             // 2
    private:
        static const unsigned int _size = TDIM*3;
};
```

The choice between 1 and 2 is largely stylistic.  They are both resolved at compile time when used in a way that demands a compile-time result.  Do you want your clients to type `()` or not?  Is there generic code that will need to use one style or the other?  Satisfying the requirements of generic code is key here.

Use of the `inline` keyword has no impact here.  I consider it overly verbose, but it does no harm and has no impact if you use it.

Adding `const` to a return type will have no impact here.  I consider it overly verbose, but it does no harm and has no impact if you use it.

If you use the function style, but do not use `constexpr`:

```
    static unsigned int size() {return _size;}
```

then this function can not be called at compile-time, and thus can not be used in a context which expects a compile-time constant.  That may not cause any harm for your application or your clients if they don't need such functionality.  But imho, if you've got `constexpr` in the toolbox, this is the perfect place to use it.  If you do a future client can do stuff like this:

```
template <unsigned N> struct B {};
constexpr auto myclass = MyClass<3>();
// ...
// lots of code here
// ...
B<myclass.size()> b;
```

These two are equivalent:

```
        static constexpr unsigned int dim = TDIM;        // 2
        static const unsigned int dim = TDIM;            // 3
```

but only because the involved type is integral.  If the type is not integral, then you have to use `constexpr` and the type has to have a `constexpr` constructor:

```
class A
{
    unsigned _i;
public:
    constexpr A(unsigned i) : _i(i) {}
};

template<unsigned int TDIM> class MyClass 
{
    public:
        static constexpr unsigned int size() {return _size;}
        static constexpr unsigned int dim = TDIM;
        static constexpr A a = A(dim);
    private:
        static const unsigned int _size = TDIM*3;
};
```

Everyone here, including myself, is still learning how to use `constexpr`.  So +1 on the question.

Comment: Shouldn't `_size` also carry `constexpr`, to be accessible from a `constexpr` function (without losing `constexpr`)?

Comment: It can, but doesn't have to since `static const unsigned int _size = TDIM*3;` and `static constexpr unsigned int _size = TDIM*3;` are the exact same thing as pointed out in my `dim = TDIM;` example.

Comment: Note that, for C++14 compatibility, the `constexpr` `size()` accessor should probably also be `const`, e.g. `static constexpr unsigned int size() const {return _size;}`.

Comment: @CliffL.Biffle:  You bring up a good point about the changing rules for non-static `constexpr` member functions.  However in this case the member function is `static` and therefore can be neither `const` nor non-`const`.

Answer (score 0):

static const integer values are treated as constants and not as variables by the compiler. They might not end up taking any memory at all depending on the constant. In all your examples, the function will return a constant value and will pretty much always get inlined (as mentioned above, the inline keyword isn't necessary in this example since all declarations are inline already).

The above code isn't different from the perspective of the compiler than this:

```
static unsigned int size() { return 42; }
```

Also the 'const' keyword in version 2 is not necessary. I believe it only makes sense if you return a pointer or a reference.

Comment: There is definitely a difference between an ordinary `static` member function returning `int` and a `static constexpr` member function returning `int`: the latter can be used in const expressions, the former cannot.

Comment: I was under the impression that version 3 uses the constexpr.